# How to deny access to a particular wordpress site url

Tags: htaccess

How can I deny access particular WordPress site page using a `.htaccess` file?

The URL to the file is: https://www.mhi-ipt.in/error/README.

The above page information came from where Apache server or elsewhere I guess.

I can't seem to find a way to disable this, probably because I'm using a shared hosting server.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you take your time and rephrase your post? As it stands, it is not quite clear what your challenge is(are) and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: how to disable this informations because the site auditing team told me totally disable without site affecting so how to overcome this plz advice me.. @nyedidikeke sir..

Comment: Any update(s) using the updated solution right [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/257781/105480)?

Comment: Can you please file an [edit] to your question – instead of commenting? And please, get some friend who speaks English well to help you with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent access to the file in question by modifying your `.htaccess` file or creating one, should you have none, with content as follow:

```
# BEGIN Prevent access to README
<Files "README">
    order allow, deny
    deny from all
</Files>
# END Prevent access to README
```

*Please note: your `.htaccess` file should be located in the same directory as the file in question; either: in your `error` folder.*

Comment: that error file is outside of the wordpress directory, so changing the wordpress htaccess will not help

Comment: @MarkKaplun: can you please elaborate? What do you suggest then? I don't see how modifying a `.htaccess` file and/or creating one wouldn't address this challenge. This seem to me a non-WordPress dominant challenge by the way.

Comment: hmm maybe I didn't understand the question.... but errors usually are generated on web server configuration level. so it depends if the htaccess can even modify access to the error, and if the site is even in the root. If the site is on a subdirectory than no htaccess changes to the file generated by wordpress will be able to help here as htaccess only have impact on the directory in which it is located and its sub directories

Comment: looking at it properly I see it is a web server generated page. retracted the downvote, but this answer is most likely wrong, or not the best way to do it

Comment: I have added these in my /htaccess but the page is opening# BEGIN Prevent access to name-of-file.extension                                                       
<Files "/error/READE.html">
    order allow, deny
    deny from all
</Files>
# END Prevent access to name-of-file.extension

Comment: Updated my answer as well @MarkKaplun, for clarity and enhancement based on our discussion. It will be great you share reason(s) why you feel *it's most likely wrong or not the best way to address the challenge in question* so as to help contribute to the community. It may be something I don't know or failed to realise! Will be glad to have your response, improvement to my post and or a solution to the OP, as we all learn.

Comment: @muprabakaran, the page is README, not README.html, doesn't it? BTW why don't you just delete the README file?

Comment: @muprabakaran: updated my post with your specific file name. [@hcheung](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/111577/hcheung) have a valid point: about the name of your file. Also: remember your `.htaccess` file is to be located in the same directory as your `README` file.

Comment: @muprabakaran: your `.htaccess` should be located in your `error` folder and should have the following as content: `<Files "README">
    order allow, deny
    deny from all
</Files>`

Comment: Actually these file and informations came from apache web server but my hosting is shared hosting not a dedicated hosting, so i would not find these file where to located in my server. @hcheung

Comment: @MarkKaplun: any idea? Can you share your insight about an effective way to address the challenge?

Comment: @muprabakaran, I don't get it, maybe you should share the directory structure of your root directory. If you don't have the access to the directory /error, then you won't be able to setup .htacess in the directory either. Maybe you should contact your hosting company if that's the case, your problem not really related to WordPress then.

Comment: if it is possible to redirect the url from https://www.mhi-ipt.in/error/README to https://www.mhi-ipt.in/ (home page..)

Comment: Can you please all move to chat? This is a serious comment explosion. Comments are meant for clarification and not extended discussion. Thanks.

Comment: @kaiser: How can that be achieved please?

Comment: Here is a link to [chat]. Aside from that, you already should have seen a note here with a link to chat.